# How to make a customizable graph

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d

I'm looking to use the java2d API to make a graph in which users can manipulate certain features using their mouse - such as the scale used for an axis or move around the different points plotted on the graph.

So far all I have found is the drawX methods on a Graphics2D object, however there does not seem to be an easy way to capture a user clicking on one of these and moving it so that I can redraw the graph.

Can anyone suggest the best/easiest way to implement this? Just looking for a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Not reinventing the wheel is always the best way, there are plenty of excellent libraries you can use: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/

If you are looking to implement this yourself, you would listen to mouse events on whatever component you're actually using to display your chart (say a JPanel), and then would have to convert between screen and chart coordinates to figure out what you need to change.

Comment: Oh, and to be slightly pedantic: what you are talking about are "charts", a "graph" is a set of vertices connected by edges. Less confusing that way.